# Getting started with python: Can't run makefile

Tags: python, makefile

I am currently starting with python and I am trying to use an open source model of the [German energy network](https://www.power.scigrid.de/pages/downloads.html). This model uses a makefile to automize several steps of the code. The issue is now that I don't get the makefile running. I using Windows with JupyterLab in my Mozilla Browser. I have also finished the steps from the section 'Before running the makefile...'

I have opened the code path with JupyterLab and if I am writing simply 'make test' (as given in the model's documentation) into the Console, I get a syntax error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-14-8152ed2c6ffd>", line 1
    make test
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried to google my way to the issue, tried to install py-make (which documentation/application I didn't really understand) and used cmd instead of JupyterLab. None of it worked.

I guess this is more a starter issue, as I know from googling that the command should be working. Nevertheless, here's the code from the Makefile:

```
###################################################################################
#                                                                                 #
#   Copyright "2015" "NEXT ENERGY"                                                #
#                                                                                 #
#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");               #
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.              #
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at                                       #
#                                                                                 #
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0                                #
#                                                                                 #
#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software           #
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,             #
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.      #
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and           #
#   limitations under the License.                                                #
#                                                                                 #
###################################################################################

################################## IMPORTANT ######################################
#
# Before running the makefile check the following:
#
# I.   Make sure that you installed PostgreSQL, osmosis and osm2pgsql on your system.
#
# II.  Adjust the config.txt file accordingly to your environment (e.g. adopted 
#      folder structure, location of binary files, database connection etc).
#
# III. Make sure that the different paths, options, etc. in the config file are set 
#      correctly. These settings are passed to variables of this makefile in the 
#      section 'Environment Varibles'. The paths are based on the folder sturcture
#      delivered with the SciGRID code. Change the paths according to where the data,
#      the tools and software used are located on your system.
#
# IV.  Make sure that the name of the databases provided in the config.txt is unique.
#      Otherwise, the makefile will override existing data in the database.
#      Note, the user can run "make drop_database" to drop an existing database.


################################## OUTLINE ########################################
# This makefile executes the following tasks:
#
# Step1. 
#   Download the OSM raw data.
#
# Step2. 
#   Filter the OSM raw data from step1 spatially (polyfile) for OSM raw power data.
#
# Step3.
#   Export the OSM filtered power data (from step2) to the created database. 
#       
# Step4. 
#   Execute the abstraction script on the database created in step3 to obtain the 
#   abstracted transmission network.
#   Stores a vizualization of the abstracted network. 
#
# Step5.
#   Stores the vertices and links of the abstracted network to .csv files.
#
# Step Update. 
#   Update your database and the network topology. 

#=================================================================================#
#              Setting the config file                                            #
#=================================================================================# 

config:=default_config.mk
include $(config)

#=================================================================================#
#              Environment Variables                                              #
#=================================================================================# 

export PGCLUSTER=$(postgres_cluster)
export PGDATABASE=$(postgres_database)
export PGUSER=$(postgres_user)
export PGPORT=$(postgres_port)
export PGHOSTADDR=$(postgres_host)
export PGPASS=$(postgres_password)
export JAVACMD_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=$(osmosis_tmp_folder)

#=================================================================================#
#              Output Files                                                       #
#=================================================================================# 

TOPOLOGY_CSV:=  $(network_folder)/vertices_$(postgres_database).csv $(network_folder)/vertices_ref_id_$(postgres_database).csv 
TOPOLOGY_PLOT:= $(visualization_folder)/topology_$(postgres_database).png

#=================================================================================#
#              Definition of tasks                                                #
#=================================================================================# 


.PHONY: all
.PHONY: scigrid
.PHONY: filter_OSM
.PHONY: download
.PHONY: clean_all
.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: drop_database
.PHONY: topology
.PHONY: test


# Performs automaticly the steps that were needed.
scigrid: topology
    @echo "--> All done." 

all: clean_all download filter_OSM scigrid topology

test: 
    @echo 'Running a test SciGRID abstraction using the OSM data for the state of Bremen (Germany):'
    @$(MAKE) OSM_raw_data_URL=http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bremen-latest.osm.pbf OSM_raw_data=../data/01_osm_raw_data/bremen-latest.osm.pbf download
    @$(MAKE) OSM_raw_power_data=../data/02_osm_raw_power_data/br_power_latest.osm.pbf OSM_raw_data=../data/01_osm_raw_data/bremen-latest.osm.pbf osmosis_tmp_folder=/tmp filter_OSM
    @$(MAKE) OSM_raw_power_data=../data/02_osm_raw_power_data/br_power_latest.osm.pbf postgres_database=br_power_latest scigrid


# Step5: Save the network topology as CSV files
topology: log/abstraction.done
    @echo "\n### Step5 ### \nSaving network topology as CSV files to folder '$(network_folder)':"
    @psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM vertices ORDER BY v_id) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '''' ENCODING 'UTF8';" > $(network_folder)/vertices_$(postgres_database).csvdata
    @psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY l_id) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '''' ENCODING 'UTF8';" > $(network_folder)/links_$(postgres_database).csvdata
    @psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM vertices_ref_id ORDER BY v_id) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '''' ENCODING 'UTF8';" > $(network_folder)/vertices_ref_id_$(postgres_database).csvdata
    @echo "--> Done. Saving network topology as CSV files."

# Step4: Execute the abstraction script on the database created in step3
log/abstraction.done: log/database_import.done
    @echo "\n### Step4 ### \nRunning the abstraction script SciGRID.py on the database '$(postgres_database)':"
    @if [ $(postgres_password) =  ]; \
    then \
    python SciGRID.py -U $(postgres_user) -P $(postgres_port) -H $(postgres_host) -D $(postgres_database) ;\
    else \
    python SciGRID.py -U $(postgres_user) -P $(postgres_port) -H $(postgres_host) -D $(postgres_database) -X $(postgres_password) ; \
    fi
    @if [ ! -e ../data/04_visualization/topology_$(postgres_database).png ]; then mv ../data/04_visualization/topology_$(postgres_database).png $(visualization_folder)/topology_$(postgres_database).png; fi
    @touch log/abstraction.done
    @echo "--> Done. SciGRID abstraction."

# Step3: Export the OSM filtered power data (from step2) to the created database.
log/database_import.done:
    @if [ -e $(OSM_raw_power_data) ]; then echo "\n### Step3 ### \nExport the OSM filtered power data \n   '$(OSM_raw_power_data)' \nto the database \n   '$(postgres_database)':"; else echo "$(OSM_raw_power_data) does not exist.";  exit 1; fi
    @if (! psql --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -lqt | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -wq $(postgres_database)); \
    then \
    createdb --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) $(postgres_database) > log/database.log 2>&1; \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -q -f $(postgis) >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -q -f $(spatial_ref_sys) >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -c "CREATE EXTENSION hstore;" >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -c "CREATE TABLE vertices_ref_id (v_id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, osm_id bigint, osm_id_typ char, visible smallint);" >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    if [ -e ../data/03_network/vertices_ref_id.csvdata ] ; \
    then \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -q -c "COPY vertices_ref_id FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '''' ENCODING 'UTF8';" < ../data/03_network/vertices_ref_id.csvdata >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -q -c "SELECT setval('vertices_ref_id_v_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(v_id) FROM vertices_ref_id));" >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -q -c "UPDATE vertices_ref_id SET visible = '0';" >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    echo "Created new database and imorted vertices_ref_id.csvdata into table vertices_ref_id."; \
    else \
    echo "Did not find vertices_ref_id.csvdata. \nThus, created new database with an empty vertices_ref_id table. \nBe aware, that the network topology may has different v_id's compared to the SciGRID release v0.2. "; \
    fi \
    else \
    psql --dbname=$(postgres_database) --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) -q -c "UPDATE vertices_ref_id SET visible = '0';" >> log/database.log 2>&1; \
    fi
    @$(osm2pgsql_bin) -r pbf --username=$(postgres_user) --database=$(postgres_database) --host=$(postgres_host) --port=$(postgres_port) -s \
    -C $(osm2pgsql_cache) --hstore --number-processes $(osm2pgsql_num_processes) --style $(stylefile) $(OSM_raw_power_data) > log/osm2pgsql.log 2>&1
    @touch log/database_import.done
    @echo "--> Done. Database import."


# Step2: Filter the OSM raw data from step1 spatially (polyfile) for OSM raw power data.
filter_OSM:
    @if [ -e $(OSM_raw_data) ]; then echo "\n### Step2 ### \nFilter the OSM raw data from step1 for power data and spatially with \n   $(polyfile):"; else echo "$(OSM_raw_data) does not exist.";  exit 1; fi
    @$(osmosis_bin) \
    --read-pbf file=$(OSM_raw_data) \
    --tag-filter accept-relations route=power \
    --used-way --used-node \
    --bounding-polygon file=$(polyfile) completeRelations=yes \
    --buffer outPipe.0=route \
    --read-pbf file=$(OSM_raw_data) \
    --tag-filter accept-relations power=* \
    --used-way --used-node \
    --bounding-polygon file=$(polyfile) completeRelations=yes \
    --buffer outPipe.0=power \
    --read-pbf file=$(OSM_raw_data) \
    --tag-filter reject-relations \
    --tag-filter accept-ways power=* \
    --used-node \
    --bounding-polygon file=$(polyfile) completeWays=yes \
    --buffer outPipe.0=pways \
    --read-pbf file=$(OSM_raw_data) \
    --tag-filter reject-relations \
    --tag-filter reject-ways \
    --tag-filter accept-nodes power=* \
    --bounding-polygon file=$(polyfile) \
    --buffer outPipe.0=pnodes \
    --merge inPipe.0=route inPipe.1=power \
    --buffer outPipe.0=mone \
    --merge inPipe.0=pways inPipe.1=pnodes \
    --buffer outPipe.0=mtwo \
    --merge inPipe.0=mone inPipe.1=mtwo \
    --write-pbf file=$(OSM_raw_power_data) > log/osmosis.log 2>&1
    @echo "--> Done. OSM filtered power data."

# Step1: Download the OSM raw data.
download: 
    @echo "\n### Step1 ### \nDownload the OSM raw data from \n   '$(OSM_raw_data_URL)' \nand saving it to \n   '$(OSM_raw_data)':"
    @wget -nv -O $(OSM_raw_data) $(OSM_raw_data_URL) > log/download.log 2>&1 
    @echo "--> Done. Download OSM raw data."

# If you wish to drop your database
drop_database:
    $(eval answer := $(shell read -r -p "Do you really want to delete the SciGRID database '$(postgres_database)'? Type 'yes' if you are sure you wish to continue: " ANSWER; echo $$ANSWER))
    @if [ "$(answer)" = "yes" ]; then if(dropdb --username=$(postgres_user) --port=$(postgres_port) --host=$(postgres_host) $(postgres_database)); then echo "The SciGRID database '$(postgres_database)' has been dropped."; fi else echo "\nDid not drop the SciGRID database '$(postgres_database)'."; fi

# Using 'make clean' implies to perform neccessary steps except from download and filter of OSM raw data afterwards
clean:
    @rm -f log/*.done
    @find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
    @echo 'Done. clean'

# Use 'make clean_all' only if you really want to start from scratch by downloading the OSM raw data and performing all steps
clean_all:
    @rm -f $(TOPOLOGY_CSV) 
    @rm -f $(TOPOLOGY_PLOT)
    @rm -f log/*
    @rm -f *.pyc
    @echo 'Done. clean_all'
```

Comment: `make` isn't a python command, it should run in linux or using build tools in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make files are no python scripts. Jupyter expects python scripts. You probably need to use the makefile from the terminal.

Not sure how well make files work on windows you probably need to do this on Linux.

That's just what I assume though I didn't read the documentation.